# Creating new numpy array using another "template" array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have:

```
x1 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

and:

```
x2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
```

with the same shape

now i want to "put x2 ontop of x1" and sum up all the numbers of x1 corresponding to the numbers of x2

so the end result is:

```
end = [1+4 ,3+2]  # end[0] is the sum of all numbers of x1 where a 0 was in x2
```

this is a naive implementation using list to further clarify the question

```py
store_0 = 0
store_1 = 0
x1 = [1, 3, 4, 2]
x2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
for value_x1 ,value_x2 in zip(x1 ,x2):
    if value_x2 == 0:
        store_0 += value_x1
    elif value_x2 == 1:
        store_1 += value_x1
```

so my question:
is there is a way to implement this in numpy without
using loops or in general just faster?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Completely unclear to me how you get from `x1`, `x2` to `end`

Comment: @flakes: It means `end[i]` is the mean of the values in `x1` whose corresponding value in `x2` is `i`.

Comment: Okay so, `x1` has 8 values, and the end result has 3 values. It's clearly not one to one then. And when you say "take the mean" you don't mention which values to take the mean of. Show the exact calculation that goes into deriving each of `[4, 5, 6]`

Comment: I have a solution if this gets re-opened

Comment: So I'll add as a comment. Start off with arrays `x1, x2 = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4]), np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])` and then sort x1 by how x2 would be sorted: `sort = x2.argsort(); x1, x2 = x1[sort], x2[sort]` This gives `[1, 4, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1]`. Then you want to find out every time x2 changes value to figure out how to split `x1`. In this case you can do `split = np.flatnonzero(x2[1:] != x2[:-1]) + 1`. Pass that to `grouped = np.split(x1, split)`. Finally sum up all the sections: `end = np.array(list(map(np.sum, grouped)))`

Comment: "template" might be the wrong word to use here - it has a specific meaning for numpy, dealing with the views that get created by slicing.  E..g in `arr2 = arr1[::2]`, `arr1` is the template for creating `arr2`.  Title might be better as "sum numpy array by category given in another numpy array"

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `unique` values in the array `x2` then for each unique value in `x2` compare it with `x2` to create a boolean mask, then apply this boolean mask on `x1` to filter the elements and take the `sum` of all filtered elements

```
x1 = np.array(x1)
[x1[x2 == v].sum() for v in np.unique(x2)]
```

Sample run:

```
# For 1D array
# x1 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
# x2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]

[5, 5]

# For 2D array
# x1 = [[1, 4, 4, 4], 
#       [6, 6, 7, 8]]

# x2 = [[0, 1, 2, 0], 
#       [2, 1, 0, 2]]

[12, 10, 18]
```